# How django-filter called inside class based view?

Tags: django, django-views

I am just trying to work with django-filters. Below are the details :

### filters.py

```
import django_filters
from .models import work_allocation

class WorkFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = work_allocation
        fields = '__all__'
```

### views.py

```
from .filters import WorkFilter

class get_task_list(ListView):
    model = work_allocation
    myFilter = WorkFilter()
```

### work.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>List of Tasks</h2>

<form method="GET">
    {{myFilter.form}}
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But I do not see any changes on my web page. Is that the right way I am calling filter? Please suggest

Comment: I can achieve my purpose through function based views, but I wanted to work with class based views.

Comment: Please add details like what error you face implementing this